# Comparison between nodejs addons and wasm

Tags: node.js, electron, webassembly, node-addon-api

Which is the better way to intergrate C/C++ or Rust code into Electron App for CPU intensive tasks, nodejs addons or wasm? Please compare these two methods in efficiency, compatibility and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Wasm is guaranteed to be compatible with any operating system that can run your Electron application.

C, C++, and Rust will not have this guarantee.  They will be more efficient, except for the overhead of being called from JavaScript.

The overhead of calling Wasm from JavaScript is actively being worked on and in the process of being either reduced or totally eliminated.